# after refreshing the page the initialValues are gone

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am using "redux-form": "^8.1.0", and noted that if initialValues are flexible (for instance in my case I get `title`from my redux state ) after refreshing my page the initial values are not displayed in the field unless I put `this.props.initialize(this.props.initialValues);` inside my render.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ streams }, props) => {
  const stream = streams[props.streamId];
  return {
    initialValues: {
      title: stream ? stream.title : null
    }
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(blabla);
```

Answer (score 1):

ok figured it out, I should add `enableReinitialize : true`